# Is there dictionary of words with similar spelling of English and Russian languages?

Tags: узус, английский

I'm looking for table or database or just a list of words with similar spelling on both languages, English and Russian.

E.g.

```
stool = стул
carousel = карусель
apogee = апогей
cigarette = сигарета
scarf = шарф
soup = суп
```

Including the words that comes to Russian from English, like molasses - меласса, черная патока. Or dramatic - драматический, pacifist - пацифист, segment - сегмент, datagram - дейтаграмма, mayor - мэр, buffet - буфет, chloroform - хлороформ.

And the way to speak English so that it is heard as a pure Russian. Native-speakers of both languages understand the same, crystal-cleanly.

Comment: The first part of your question is too wide.  There are likely thousands of such words.  Most words from Latin language would qualify as would most words from English. I don't really understand the second part (the way to speak English).

Comment: I'm exactly in lurching of thousands of such words. The second part means that speaker says something on one language, but native-speaker of another will understood him truly and maybe would not distinguish which language does he use.

Comment: I don't think you'll get the second part ever - because the sentences are structured differently.  Plus majority of those words would decline in Russian making them sound differently.

Comment: I would recommend to read some articles on "ложные друзья переводчика" - there you can find many examples when two similar words in Russian and English mean different things and cannot be used interchangeably. For instance - pathetic and патетический, dramatic and драматичный, killer and киллер, manager and менеджер, etc.

Comment: I don't think драматический or сегмент comes from English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should say that all the words you call "the words that come to Russian from English" actually came to Russian from German and French, Latin, and Greek (excluding the IT term).

Such dictionaries do exist, they are called `Словарь иностранных слов`, like [this one](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/), but usually they include not only the words that came from English, but from other languages, too.

Comment: Thank you for this dictionary, it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check a Russian loanword dictionary (*словарь иностранных слов*).

All the words in your example are borrowed by Russian and most probably represented there.

Please note that some of your pairs are false friends: for instance "stool" is translated as *табурет* (*стул* means "chair"); "buffet" is *шведский стол* or *фуршет* (*буфет* is "sideboard" or "bar" or "canteen") and so on.

Comment: Google think in another way, e.g. buffet: http://translate.google.com/#auto/ru/buffet or stool: http://translate.google.com/#auto/ru/stool

Comment: I'm actually think that "chair" mostly is "Кресло", like soft stool.

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow: Google translate does not often prioritize meanings properly. "Buffet" and *буфет* do have common meanings indeed. But http://goo.gl/ig4sIb, primary meaning: "a meal consisting of several dishes from which guests serve themselves". This cannot be translated as *буфет*: it's either *фуршет* (light snacks) or *шведский стол* (complete meal courses).

Comment: Are you sure? I'm really think that it is multi-sense word, like russian's "ключ", mean "key" or mean "natural well".

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow: sure of what? As I said, it is a multi-sense word (in both languages). It's just that only secondary meanings intersect, those which would yield less answers on Family Feud.

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow - Although the words can sound similar, the meaning can be a bit different. In Russian "табурет" has no back, and can be either soft or hard, and "стул" has a back, irrespective of whether it is soft or hard, and "кресло" has both a back and arms, and is usually soft.